# How to get feature importance in RF

Tags: python, pandas, random-forest

I am trying to get RF feature importance, I fit the random forest on the data like this:

```
model = RandomForestRegressor()
n = model.fit(self.X_train,self.y_train)
if n is not None:
   df = pd.DataFrame(data = n , columns = ["Feature","Importance_Score"])
   df["Feature_Name"] = np.array(self.X_Headers)
   df = df.drop(["Feature"], axis = 1)
   df[["Feature_Name","Importance_Score"]].to_csv("RF_Importances.csv", index = False)
   del df
```

However, the `n` variable returns `None`, why is this happening?

Comment: I'm aware of 3 ways to get RF feature importance https://mljar.com/blog/feature-importance-in-random-forest/ (1) you can use built-in importance (2) permutation-based importance or (3) SHAP-based importance. I'm using permutation-based importance. All methods are sensitive to a high correlation between features.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, what do you mean by high correlation I mean what is criteria for that? is it above .7 for example? Also, what if indeed my features are highly correlated?

Comment: Check the correlation between features and then check if one of the highly correlated features is not selected as the least important. Highly correlated means about > 0.8

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried the first two methodologies, they get almost the same conclusion. However, I checked the correlation I the maximum value of .62 I don't know if it's high correlation. I get values of the importance scores to have one feature only having .85 and the rest .15 are dividing between the other 10 features. Thus I expected that only the first feature has the most contirubtion, so when I dropped the other features and trained the first feature only, I expected to have almost the same testing results because other features are not contibuting so much. However it

Comment: However it wasn';t the case, he abs error percentage of the testing data increased significantly from 14.13010% to 22.96036%. do you have any explanation for this?

Comment: It means that the correlation between two features is significant enough to trick feature importance methods. You should keep both features in the model. In my AutoML https://github.com/mljar/mljar-supervised I'm using following trick to test if I need a feature. I add a random feature to the training data and compute feature importance for all features. If feature importance is smaller than importance of random feature, then I drop such feature.

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure how `model.fit(self.X_train,self.y_train)` is supposed to work. Need more information about how you set up the model.

If we set this up using simulated data, it works:

```
np.random.seed(111)
X = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(0,1,(100,5)),columns=['A','B','C','D','E'])
y = np.random.normal(0,1,100)

model = RandomForestRegressor()
n = model.fit(X,y)
if n is not None:
   df = pd.DataFrame({'features':X.columns,'importance':n.feature_importances_})

df
 
  features  importance
0        A    0.176091
1        B    0.183817
2        C    0.169927
3        D    0.267574
4        E    0.202591
```